# How to test Scotty endpoints

Tags: haskell, testing, endpoint, scotty

With the following [Scotty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) endpoint:

```hs
myendpoint :: Text -> ScottyM ()
myendpoint info =
    post "/foo/bar/:var" $ do
        var :: Text <- param "var"
        query :: Query <- jsonData
        result <- liftIO $ retrieveResult info var query
        json $ result

runApi :: IO ()
runApi = scotty 4602 $ do
    myendpoint
```

How to test `myendpoint` with different possible inputs, for instance

```hs
info1 = "foo"
query1 = Query { qParam1 = "foo", qParam2 = "bar" }
var1 = "bar"
expect1 = Result { foo = "foo", bar = "bar" }

res1 = decode $ test_myendpoint info1 query1 var1
res1 `shouldBe` expect1

info2 = "baz"
query2 = Query { qParam1 = "hello", qParam2 = "there" }
var2 = "boo"
expect2 = Result { foo = "biz", bar = "dev" }

res2 = decode $ test_myendpoint info2 query2 var2
res2 `shouldBe` expect2
```

I'm tempted to simply run the API in another thread, then query the endpoint for real with some JSON, but is there a cleaner way to do this? (although the benefit of the above would be real end-to-end testing)

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Need to import `hspec-wai` and `hspec-wai-json`.

Then instead of running the api directly, we create an `api` function that returns an `IO Application`, and then another `runApi` function that actually runs the thing.

```hs
import           Network.Wai                 (Application)
import           Network.Wai.Handler.Warp    (run)

api :: IO Application
api = scottyApp $ do
    myendpoint

runApi :: IO ()
runApi =
    api >>= run 460
```

Now we're free to use `with api` in the tests:

```hs
import           Test.Hspec
import           Test.Hspec.Wai      as W
import           Test.Hspec.Wai.JSON

spec :: Spec
spec = with api $ do
    describe "testing some endpoint" $ do
        it "should return correct data" $ do
            get "/foo/bar/whatever" `shouldRespondWith`
                [json|{foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}|]
```